# Golang jsonable pointers to different structs in slice

Tags: json, pointers, struct, go

My golang program have this structure of structs:

```
type JSONDoc struct {
     Count  int         `json:"count"`
     Objects []uintptr  `json:"objects"`
}

type ObjectA struct {
     FieldA string
}

type ObjectB struct {
     FieldB string
}
```

I don't know what object types can be in JSONDoc.Objects, i'm need to store multiple structs in json array. `Reflect` returns pointers to structs, i'm appending them to struct, but `encoding/json` package in result json replace pointer with integer address. 
Also unsafe.Pointer cannot be parsed by `encoding/json` too.

Just want result json to look as

```
{
     "count":2, 
     "objects":
     [
         {"FieldA":"..."}, 
         {"FieldB":"..."}
     ]
}
```

How can i store pointers to structs that will be correctly encoded to json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `interface{}`, for example :

```
type JSONDoc struct {
    Count   int           `json:"count"`
    Objects []interface{} `json:"objects"`
}

func main() {
    doc := JSONDoc{Count: 2}
    doc.Objects = append(doc.Objects, &ObjectA{"A"}, &ObjectB{"B"}) 
    b, err := json.MarshalIndent(&doc, "", "\t")
    fmt.Println(string(b), err)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/Kr71h4xhut)